# How can I use Math.random() to make rare to common outcomes

Tags: jquery, random

I am working on a system where an image is replaced after a random amount of time. However I currently have it choose between the numbers 1-5 for display purposes. I was wondering if I could use Math.random() to make some numbers rarer than others. For example if I want number 1 to appear commonly, but want number 5 to be really rare, can I do that with Math.random()? If not what can do that?

Code I currently have:

```
$(function() {
$("#test").click(function() {
    randomGen();
});

function randomGen() {
var rand = Math.floor((Math.random() * 5) + 1);
var test = Math.floor((Math.random() * 15000) + 1);
    if (rand === 1) { 
        console.log(rand);
    }
    if (rand === 2) {
        console.log(rand);
    }
    if (rand === 3) {
        console.log(rand);
    }
    if (rand === 4) {
        console.log(rand);
    }
    if (rand === 5) {
        console.log(rand);
    }
setTimeout(randomGen, test);
}
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Math.Random is not suitable to be directly used to make some numbers appear more often than others.

You can however, add you own "weighting" function, something like this:

```
//Returns a random with a 20% chance of 1, 40% chance of 2 or 3
function WeightedRandom()
{
    var num = Math.random() * 100;

    if(num < 20)
        return 1;
    if(num < 60)
        return 2;
    else return 3;
}
```

This is of course highly manual and I'm sure you can think of a clever way to make it more automated.

Comment: It is telling me "Uncaught ReferenceError: r is not defined", I don't know if you forgot to define it or I was supposed to define it or what XD

Comment: Sorry, I was being dumb and wrote it in C# first. :)

Comment: Awesome it works! Now I have another issue where it stops after 2 or 3 times and it doesn't repeat even though I have setTimeout(WeightedRandom, test); where test is defined and is given a random number. Not sure why it's happening.

Comment: I'm not sure why that is happening, but please make sure to mark this as correct if it solved your problem - and feel free to ask another question for your new problem :)

Comment: Haha yeah, I'll have to wait the 90 minutes to ask another one :P Thank you again!

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
var rand = Math.floor(Math.pow(Math.random(), 2) * 5 + 1);
```

By squaring the random number between 0 and 1, the distribution is skewed towards the lower numbers. This makes 1 more common than 2, which is more common than 3, etc. If you wish to adjust the distribution, or change things around, adjust the exponent.

Comment: This is not right.  This is simply applying a function to the numbers to make them fit an exponential curve, not making them explicitly weighted.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9: This is probably what the OP means. It is a lot simpler than a true weighting function, since it adjusts the distribution mathematically.